# SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse a String to JSON in NodeJS/Javascript, this is my string (which I cannot change, coming from an external database):

```
'{\\"value1\\":\\"XYZ\\",\\"value2\\":\\"ZYX\\"}'
```

I'm calling:

```
JSON.parse(row.raw_data)
```

But are getting:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position
```

I actually thought double escape was the correct way of escaping in string/JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. You've said you can't change it, which is unfortunate.

It *looks* like it's been double-stringified but then the outermost quotes have been left off. If so, you can fix it by adding `"` at each end and then double-parsing it, like this:

```js
var str = '{\\"value1\\":\\"XYZ\\",\\"value2\\":\\"ZYX\\"}';
str = '"' + str + '"';
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(str));
console.log(obj);
```

Ideally, though, you'll want to go through the database and correct the invalid data.

> I actually thought double escape was the correct way of escaping in string/JSON.

In JSON, strings are wrapped in double quotes (`"`), not double escapes. You only escape double quotes *within* strings (with a single `\`).

If you've been creating JSON strings manually (in code), **don't**. :-) Instead, create the structure you want to save, and then stringify it. Building JSON strings manually is error-prone, but a proper JSON stringifier will be reliable.

Comment: I initially thought of cutting the backslahes away using a regex, but your solution is way better. So I cancelled writing my own answer, and can only say: upvote :-)